# Javascript confusion and modal boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

So I'm making a button where whenever you click it a window will kind of appear and when you click anything other than the window it will disappear.

I got the window to pop-out and it does change the opacity of the background to look invisible but for some reason, every time I click the bottom of the window it disappears, it doesn't disappear whenever I click outside of the window, and the opacity never changes back to its original form.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-box');

$('.button-func').click(function(){
    $('.filter-box').animate({height:"toggle", opacity:"toggle"}, "slow");
    $('.header').animate({opacity:'.6'});
    $('.topnav').animate({opacity:'.6'});
    $('.add-filter').animate({opacity:'.6'});
    $('.main_home_box').animate({opacity:'.6'});
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        $('.header').animate({opacity:'1'});
        $('.topnav').animate({opacity:'1'});
        $('.add-filter').animate({opacity:'1'});
        $('.main_home_box').animate({opacity:'1'});
    }
}
```

fairly new to js, sorry if it's a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some problem in your window.onclick event logic, if target==modal on document code shouldn't execute and if target!=modal means target is outside of your box.
Try it.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-box');

$('.button-func').click(function(){
    $('.filter-box').animate({height:"toggle", opacity:"toggle"}, "slow");
    $('.header').animate({opacity:'.6'});
    $('.topnav').animate({opacity:'.6'});
    $('.add-filter').animate({opacity:'.6'});
    $('.main_home_box').animate({opacity:'.6'});
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target != modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        $('.header').animate({opacity:'1'});
        $('.topnav').animate({opacity:'1'});
        $('.add-filter').animate({opacity:'1'});
        $('.main_home_box').animate({opacity:'1'});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As piyush suggested, window.click should be this function.

```
function(event) {
if (event.target != modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    $('.header').animate({opacity:'1'});
    $('.topnav').animate({opacity:'1'});
    $('.add-filter').animate({opacity:'1'});
    $('.main_home_box').animate({opacity:'1'});
}
}
```

**The problem that still remains is that when you click anywhere the event target is not what you are expecting**. For example when you click on a text box inside the modal window, the event target is the textbox and not the modal window. You have to change your logic to recognize whether the user clicked inside the modal window or outside.
`event.target != modal` is not an accurate check.You can use event.target.path property to figure this out.
Hope this helps. Queries are welcome.